# Is there a way of referencing the xml comments to avoid duplicating them?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

This is not a biggie at all, but something that would be very helpful indeed if resolved.

When I'm overloading methods etc there are times when the xml comments are exactly the same, bar 1 or 2 param names.  I have to copy/paste the comments down to each overloaded method, where they are the same.  Sometimes, however, this can cause misleading information about the method if I update one of them and forget to go back and copy/paste them to all others.  If there are alot of overloaded methods, this can be very time consuming and prone to error.

So I'm wondering if there is a way of storing comments in one place (like a variable), which I can simply reference instead.  This way, one change will be reflected across all related commetns.

Here's an example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Go and do something
    /// </summary>
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(true, "Done something");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Go and do something
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="doIt">whether it should be done or not</param>
    public void DoSomething(bool doIt)
    {
        DoSomething(doIt, "Done something");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Go and do something cool
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="doIt">whether it should be done or not</param>
    /// <param name="doneMessage">message to show once done</param>
    public void DoSomething(bool doIt, string doneMessage)
    {
        if (doIt)
            Console.WriteLine(doneMessage);
    }
```

So as you can see, all of the comments are the same except I decided to make a correction on the last one to read 'Go and do something cool'.  Now i'll have to go and change this is all the other method comments too.

Cheers.

Comment: +1  I was allways afraid to ask this question.

Comment: @Peter - Fair point, yes I've been pretty crap with that. i'll sort it, cheers

Comment: thing is, with that rate people will stop answering your questions...you don't want that :)  ...or maybe I'm wrong, you got three answers to this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to these specifications:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx

There is no set standard for XML comments; the ones shown on that page are just "recommended". In the recommended tags, there is no such feature. However, the XML documentation tool happily accepts the following with no warning:

```
/// <summary id="30">foo</summary>
void bar();

/// <summary id="30"/>
void bar(int baz);
```

Whether this is useful to you or not depends on what exactly you do with the XML file that the compiler spits out. Unfortunately, things like Intellisense (code completion and in-IDE tooltips, etc). won't do anything with it.

EDIT: Try out `<include>`, as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h8dy30z.aspx . It's a bit heavyweight, because it requires a separate file, but if your documentation is enormous it could be worth it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do this (tested in VS 2019 16.11) by using [the `<inheritdoc>` tag with a `cref` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#inheritdoc) making sure you reference the appropriate "parent" overload.

So in your example you can reference the overload which has the most documentation and intellisense will use all it can from that method:

```cs
    /// <inheritdoc cref="DoSomething(bool, string)"/>
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(true, "Done something");
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="DoSomething(bool, string)"/>
    public void DoSomething(bool doIt)
    {
        DoSomething(doIt, "Done something");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Go and do something cool
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="doIt">whether it should be done or not</param>
    /// <param name="doneMessage">message to show once done</param>
    public void DoSomething(bool doIt, string doneMessage)
    {
        if (doIt)
            Console.WriteLine(doneMessage);
    }
```

Comment: What's more, you can also use `<inheritdoc cref=""/>` with references to types/members from imported/referenced assemblies/libraries, not just your own user-code. Neat. For example: for my own `IHttpClientFactory` extension methods I can do `/// <inheritdoc cref="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.AddHttpClient(IServiceCollection,String)" />` and VS shows the referenced XML documentation in the tooltips for my own code.

Comment: For an example that shows embedding a property summary into a constructor parameter, see [this issue comment](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/313#issuecomment-1197156566)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such function in the standard XML comments tags. [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/)  on the other hand implements [<inheritdoc/>](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/79897974-ffc9-4b84-91a5-e50c66a0221d.htm) which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an interface you can reference one of the methods from the other methods, like this:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    /// <summary>Handles this and that.</summary>
    void SomeMethod();

    /// <summary><see cref="ISomeInterface.SomeMethod()"/></summary>
    /// <param name="i">Param blabla.</param>
    void SomeMethod(int i);
}

class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
    /// <summary><see cref="ISomeInterface.SomeMethod()"/></summary>
    public void SomeMethod() { }

    /// <summary><see cref="ISomeInterface.SomeMethod(int)"/></summary>
    public void SomeMethod(int i) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call me silly, but a document-scoped search and replace for `Go and do something` coupled with conscientious use of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> may make this a moot point.  One edit - well, typed once at least.

@Reinderien's answers are informative...but not very helpful where leveraging IntelliSense or a standard processing tool is the goal.

@Peter Lillevold's answer is informative too and cooler I think in that it speaks to SHFB for processing...but still no IntelliSense.

@Paw Baltzersen's answer could be employed irrespective of employing an interface and is tempting...but does not get the IntelliSense right either.

I like the avoidance of search and replace where possible, but getting the IntelliSense right here would generally be my first concern.